# Do you need to store the std::future return value from std::async?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdasync

Consider the follow code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void func()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); });
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "start " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << "ms\n";
    func();
    std::cout << "stop  " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << "ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
start 18737230ms
stop  18738230ms
```

We can see that 1 seconds passes before `func()` returns. However there is no std::future stored from `std::async(...);` - i.e.: `auto f = std::async(...)`

This appears to work - but I am wandering what the mechanism is such that this works. If I have a std::future (auto f in my little example) then when it goes out of scope it tidies up the thread - i.e. waits for 1 second and then the thread is disposed of behind the scenes.

A further test:

```cpp
int main() {

    std::cout << "start " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << "ms\n";
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); });
    std::cout << "stop1 " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << "ms\n";
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, []{std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); });
    std::cout << "stop2 " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << "ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
start 4448133ms
stop1 4449133ms - 1 sec passed
stop2 4449133ms - almost no time passed
```

So this shows that storing the future, means that the thread runs parallel. Not storing the future means the thread appears to have to run to completion - I guess this is because a temporary future is created and destroyed?

So my conclusion is that you can't just call `std::async(...)` without storing the std::future if you want it to run in parallel (which is the whole point) - even if you don't plan to use the future.

hmm... I think I have just talked myself into the answer! - but I am not 100% sure I have the reasoning correct - hopefully I have...

Comment: std::async and std::future are really bad. use my library, concurrencpp: https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp

Comment: @DavidHaim hm, interesting - just from a quick glance - does this protect variables shared between threads automatically (somehow)? - what is the advantage over std::async otherwise? - and why do you think std::async / future are bad?

Comment: It doesn't protect shared variables, but allows results to be passed safetly between threads and consumed with `co_await`. `std::async` is just a nice wrapper for `std::thread` - not scalable at all. `std::future` also has its problems - destructor is blocking and no way to pull the asynchronous result without blocking.

Comment: @code_fodder Note: when it goes out of scope it may **not** tidy up the thread. Two years later, how do you think about it now?

Comment: @john - I am not sure what you mean? - when the future goes out of scope it *does* block and tidy up the thread - that is sort of the point of using tasks instead of managing the thread yourself, right? - two years later, I am happily using various methods of concurrency :)

Comment: @code_fodder "tidy up the thread", you mean `join` the thread. I see somewhere says that the thread may be reused later, so the thread may still alive even if the future goes out of scope.

Comment: @John well, sort of - I believe std::future/async uses a thread pool to manage the threads, so as you say the thread may or may not be joined.... but as I say, this is for the compiler/implementation to worry about - not for the user of std::future/async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `std::future` is created via `std::async`, the destructor waits for end of the task. This does not mean that the task does not run in parallel - it just waits for the end of the task at the end of scope of variable. Yet it makes usage of `std::async` without storing a `std::future` a bit tricky and I would generally recommend storing the future somewhere to avoid nasty surprises. Take a look [at page about `std::future` destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) (emphasis mine):

> these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true: **the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.**

Comment: thanks for this, but I am still wandering what happens when you don't store the future. I *think* that means a temp future is returned and destroyed right away - therefore it blocks immediately until the thread ends (so it ends up running synchronously)?

Comment: @code_fodder bascially that's it - when you don't store returned object it is removed right away - so the main thread blocks in the case of `future`

Comment: tbh the text quoted could be less cryptic. But that's how generally ISO standard rolls: let's describe what happens if we dereference null pointer as a syllogism of phrases in three different paragraphs.  Several editions later: let's add clarification into next standard.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'd call it know issue with C++ standards so ranting about it makes kinda no sense ;)

Comment: @bartop "If the std::future is created via std::async, ***the destructor waits for end of the task.***" You mean `std::async(std::launch::async, []{std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); });` creates a temporary object of `std::future` and the destructor of the said temporary object waits for the end of the task? Am I right?

Comment: @John yes, this is what I meant